# Elasticsearch python library "post" a document

Tags: python, post, elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch python library. The method create require an ID to index a document.

I cannot find in the documentation a method to "post" a document into an index. By post I mean a method that will take in charge the generation of the ID for me.

Is there any way to let ES generate the ID for me or do I have to generate a random ID by myself and use the create method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, ES will [auto-generate an ID](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/docs-index_.html#_automatic_id_generation) for you if you don't provide one.

Since you're using the ES Python library you can leverage the `index()` function and not provide any ID, ES will generate one for you.

```
client.index(index='my_index', body=mydoc)
```